# angularjs : how to get a value from asp .net page with input type hidden?

Tags: c#, angularjs

Does someone know how to do this simple thing : get a value from a hidden input field with angularjs ? Googled a lot without real success... C# in server side writes a product id, and I need to retrieve it to pass it to my angularjs json service.

Thanx a million times if you're able to answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
@functions{
        public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
        }
    }

<input id="antiForgeryToken" type="hidden" value="@GetAntiForgeryToken()" />

var antiForgeryToken = $("#antiForgeryToken").val();
```

***EDIT***

Without jQuery:

```
var antiForgeryToken = document.getElementById("antiForgeryToken").value;
```

Using the angular $document:

```
var antiForgeryToken = $document.find("#antiForgeryToken").val();
```

Comment: ok. $document.find is working, but I was trying to do it more the angularjs style. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

@Rob Jacobs has the right approach.  Essentially this:

```
$scope.myHiddenElement = $("#ctl00_cphMainContent_hConsentDisagree").val();
```

Where your hidden element is:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hConsentDisagree" runat="server">
```

Or...

```
<input type='hidden' id='ctl00_cphMainContent_hConsentDisagree' value='whatever' />
```

EDIT
To Avoid breaking the spirit of AngularJs you could change the ASP.NET piece to something like this:

```
var hiddenField = new HtmlInputHidden();
hiddenField.Value = "myValue";
hiddenField.Attributes["ng-model"] = "my-hidden-field";
```

then it's just this in the controller:

```
$scope.my-hidden-field
```

EDIT Number 2

```
var hiddenField = new HtmlInputHidden {Value = "myValue", ID = "hiddenfield"};
hiddenField.Attributes.Add("ng-model","myhiddenfield");
myDiv.Controls.Add(hiddenField);
```

Does not seem to work...  However this does:

```
$scope.myTest = $('#MainContent_hiddenfield').val();
```

Yeah...  I know, it breaks the spirit of Angular but...  sometimes you gotta just make it work.  I don't have a better answer.

Comment: ok but the purpose of angularjs is to avoid jquery : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: I have found that jQuery is not completely indispensable.  I edited my answer with another approach that should work.

Comment: See EDIT Number 2...  This was done with the built in jQuery lite that comes with AngularJs.  No external references to jQuery were used. So...  While it is still jQuery-esque, it is really Angular.

Comment: Yes, I know it's the built-in angular jqlite, but a lot of questions remains unresolved about input type hidden and the way to access it by ngModel way... Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

A small enhancement to @Rod Hartzell solutions

```
var hiddenField = new HtmlInputHidden {Value = "myValue", ID = "hiddenfield" ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static};
hiddenField.Attributes.Add("ng-model","myhiddenfield");
myDiv.Controls.Add(hiddenField);
```

and

```
$scope.myTest = $('#hiddenfield').val();
```

I've set the ClientIdMode to Static (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This way the ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try generating `ng-model="hiddenValue"` attribute on the field from server side and then try to get the value in your controller with `$scope.hiddenValue`. Of course the hidden field should be in the the scope of the controller.

Comment: did you try that yourself ?

Comment: Please add a construct of your server side and I can try it. But I don't see a reason for it not to work.